# How to draw a round map projection in R with a rectangle around specific area?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, map-projections

I need to make a map similar to this one in R, but drawing a rectangle in Uruguay:

[image]

I'm trying with ggplot, but the globe has no border, and I can't find the way to indicate the coordinates to draw the rectangle that interests me. This is what I have obtained following this [web](https://gist.github.com/rafapereirabr/26965dd851debad32ad2e659024ba451) :

[image]

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple plot without ggplot. It uses the fact that in the maps package, the orthographic projection has co-ordinates on a circle of radius 1.

```
library(maps)
library(plotrix)
map("world", proj="orthographic", orientation=c(-20,-60,0))
draw.circle(0,0,1)
rect(.01,-.27,.11,-.17, border="red")
```

[image]

If you colour the map (fill=TRUE, col="grey"), you may see that Antarctica and possibly North America get some strange errors. That's because a part of the polygon is missing in this projection, and the simple "fill" algorithms can't really deal with that.
Your own plot also has such a straight line between two extremal points on Antarctica.